# How to copy one column of data to another without deleting data in receiving column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

have an issue. I have a table called consumers. In that table there are three columns that represent the date of birth of an individual. Problem is the DOB is split into year, month, day. What I'd like to do is copy over the month and day column data to the year column ..

ex.

```
year   month   day
1971   05      21
```

After running the script, I'd like the year column to have this value in it: `19710521`

Then I'd also like to run a script to delete the leading 2 integers (the "19" of the 1971)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update consumers set year=cast(year as varchar(4))+cast(month as varchar(2))+cast(day as varchar(2))
```

this will copy data to year column

**if year column is int then**

```
 update consumers set year=cast(cast(year as varchar(4))+cast(month as varchar(2))+cast(day as varchar(2)) as int)
```

**to remove first 2 numbers**

```
 update consumers  set year= SUBSTRING(cast(year as varchar(50)),3,LEN(year)-2)
```

Comment: Thank you guys!! Appreciate it. Gonna try them out tomorrow!

Comment: Ok quick followup question...some of the fields I have to move are null. I'd like to add two zeros to those fileds... but some fields have data. I just want to add the 00 to the column and rows that are blank...any ideas?

Comment: @mhasan - I see that your statement accommodates the zero addition that I need but the query didn't work. The Select statement literally just selected and displayed the results but didn't update the table..

Comment: update cousumers set columnName='00' where columnName is null

Comment: Thanks @HbV2. Question... using your TSQL... I have some data in the month and year field that if less than 10 doesn't have the leading 0 which is messing me up bigtime one the process.what would I need to run to, if there is only 1 digit in those fields, adds a leading 0?

Comment: unfortunatel update cousumers set columnName='00' where columnName is null didn't work for some reason :-/

Comment: if ur data type is int then
update cousumers set columnName='00' where columnName
it wont set '00'

Answer (score 1):

```
Select  CAST([year] as varchar(4)) + 
        CASE WHEN [month]<10 THEN '0'+CAST([month] as varchar(2)) 
             ELSE CAST([month] as varchar(2)) END  + 
        CASE WHEN [day]<10 THEN '0'+CAST([day] as varchar(2)) 
             ELSE CAST([day] as varchar(2)) END
        as dateCol
From consumers
```

To remove first two digits

```
SELECT RIGHT(dateCol,LEN(dateCol)-2) 
FROM (

            Select  CAST([year] as varchar(4)) + 
            CASE WHEN [month]<10 THEN '0'+CAST([month] as varchar(2)) 
                 ELSE CAST([month] as varchar(2)) END  + 
            CASE WHEN [day]<10 THEN '0'+CAST([day] as varchar(2)) 
                 ELSE CAST([day] as varchar(2)) END
            as dateCol
            From consumers
     )Z
```

Comment: I think the zero will be truncated when you cast to varchar. I am getting `1971521` as result when running you query.

Comment: Nice. Now you may want to add the table name `consumers` in the `FROM` clause. And update the `year` column with the result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. so how would I make it so there is no truncation of the zero?

Comment: Awesome guys! I'll run this and let you know how it works. Thank you!!